# https requests from a Jenkins Job blocked

Tags: api, jenkins, https

I'm experiencing an issue with **https requests** sent from a **Jenkins job**, which are blocked and do not reach the final server.

The scenario is as follows:

- I have a server where I'm running some **backend**, exposing APIs both over `http` and `https` (it's a django + django rest framework backend)
- I implemented a **Rhinoceros Plugin in C#**, which needs to perform some rest API requests to the above mentioned server
- On another server, I'm running a **Jenkins job** that is responsible for compiling the plugin, installing it on Rhinoceros and run some operations on Rhinoceros for test purposes

All calls over `http` **do work** like a charm from the plugin running on the Jenkins job, but all `https` **do not work**.

**NOTES**:

- When manually running the plugin outside Jenkins, the `https` remote request succeed without any issue
- Moreover, `https` requests sent from any other location do work
- When the plugin runs from the Jenkins job no trace of any incoming connection is logged into the backend server, so that makes me believe the request never leaves the Jenkins server

**WHAT I TRIED**:

- I installed the domain certificate locally on the Jenkins server, using `keytool`, on the `JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` keystore
- I tried to install some Jenkins Plugins to skip certificate check or to trust certain domains
- I checked the firewall on the Jenkins machine (adding allow rules for both Java and Rhinoceros applications)

So far, nothing worked.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Do you need a proxy server to connect to HTTPS?

Comment: No, the backend can be accessed directly over https.